# Duplication of data in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue where there is data duplication on my query.

This is how the issue looks like.

I have a view table with data of:
(PS_CX_FINC_SF_P_VW)

```
ID | Item_Term | Item_Amt | Item_Type | Date | Item_NO
------------------------------------------------------
005976 | 1609 | 3000.00 | C | 2016-09-27 | 00010
```

(PS_CX_FINC_SF_A_VW)

```
ID | Item_Term | Item_Amt | Item_Type | Date | Item_NO
--------------------------------------------

005976 | 1609   |     -50.00  |   P   |        2016-09-27  |  00009

005976 | 1609   |     -100.00 |   P   |        2016-10-04  |  00011

005976 | 1609   |     -50.00  |   P   |        2016-10-23  |  00012
```

---

What I hope for is this results:

```
ID | Item_Amt | Date | Item_NO | Item_Amt | Date | Item_NO
----------------------------------------------

005976 | 3000.00 | 2016-09-27 | 00010 | -50.00 | 2016-09-27 | 00009

005976 | NULL | NULL | NULL | -100.00 | 2016-10-04 | 00011

005976 | NULL | NULL | NULL | -50.00 | 2016-10-23 | 00012
```

But my Result is becoming like this:

```
ID | Item_Amt | Date | Item_NO | Item_Amt | Date | Item_NO
----------------------------------------------------------

005976 | 3000.00 | 2016-09-27 | 00010 | -50.00 | 2016-09-27 | 00009

005976 | 3000.00 | 2016-09-27 | 00010 | -100.00 | 2016-10-04 | 00011

005976 | 3000.00 | 2016-09-27 | 00010 | -50.00 | 2016-10-23 | 00012
```

This are my query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.ITEM_AMT, A.DATE, A.ITEM_NO, B.ITEM_AMT, B.DATE, B.ITEM_NO
FROM PS_CX_FINC_SF_P_VW A 
LEFT JOIN PS_CX_FINC_SF_A_VW B ON (A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID AND A.ITEM_TERM = B.ITEM_TERM)
WHERE A.EMPLID = '00000005976'
AND A.ITEM_TERM = '1609'
```

The requirement is to show these 2 types of payment in one rows. I can't find a way to make the data for the first type to be showing only 1 row.

```
My Table key is 
ID , Item_Term, Date , Item_Type and Item_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having `Date` in join and use **table B as main table** and **table A in Left join**

```
SELECT B.ID, A.ITEM_AMT, A.DATE, A.ITEM_NO, B.ITEM_AMT, B.DATE, B.ITEM_NO
FROM PS_CX_FINC_SF_A_VW B
LEFT JOIN PS_CX_FINC_SF_P_VW A  ON (A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID AND A.ITEM_TERM = B.ITEM_TERM AND A.DATE = B.DATE)
WHERE B.EMPLID = '00000005976'
AND B.ITEM_TERM = '1609';
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: Its not working. the result for A now will all be null. Anyway thanks for your reply viki888

Comment: Yeah I just modified as `B.ID` to fetch from table B. This will give you exact result